# Binomial thereom to figure out coefficents

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Use the binomial theorem to find the coefficient of $x^8y^5$ in $(x + y)^{15}$

My textbook shows how to do this looking at the coefficents of Pascal's triangle but, I know theres another way using combinations. Could someone explain to me how I would figure this out without using the triangle?

Answer (score 0):

It is:

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^ky^{n-k}$$

$$(x+y)^{15}=\sum_{k=0}^{15} \binom{15}{k} x^k y^{15-k}= y^{15}+ \dots+ \binom{15}{8}x^8y^{7} + \dots + x^{15}$$

So,if we add the powers of $x$ and $y$,the result must be $15$.

At $x^8y^{5}$,if we add the powers,the result is $5+8=13 \neq 15$,so the coefficient is equal to $0$.

Comment: Just to confirm I understand, for $x^6y^3$ in $(3x-2y)^9$ I would want to say that 6+3 = 9, so what would be the coefficients for that?

Comment: @Wilson In this case, it is like that:

$$(3x-2y)^9=\sum_{k=0}^9 \binom{9}{k}(3x)^k (-2y)^{9-k}=(-2y)^9+ \dots + \binom{9}{6}(3x)^6 (-2y)^{9-6}+ \dots + (3x)^9$$

Therefore,the coefficient of $x^6y^3$ is : $$\binom{9}{6}3^6 (-2)^{9-6}=-489888$$